# How to modify .GlobalPreferences.plist file?

Tags: keyboard, automator, preferences, plist

my objective is to create a keyboard shortcut to activate/deactivate the "replace with" on Mac.
The idea is to create an automation that can be activated with a shortcut trough services.

What the shortcut does is switching two similar `.GlobalPreferences.plist` files, one with "replace with" keys one without.

Here is my code:
[image]

The problem is that for some reason it doesn't switch the files. But on a regular folder it works.

In detail: 
running `mv ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferencesTMP.plist` perfectly works, the proprieties are copied.
On the other hand if I run `mv /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences2.plist ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` It doesn't keep the proprieties of `.GlobalPreferences2.plist` but instead I got exactly the same as `.GlobalPreferences.plist` which I started with.

Comment: Does it definitely not replace the files, or does it just not acknowledge there is a new version? Most prefs like this are only read once, so changing a pref needs the file to be re-read. I'm not certain how you could force that, so I can't provide an answer.

Comment: I'd also be more tempted to use `defaults write` than swap out the files each time.

Comment: Properties are cached, so even if you just change the files, that's not enough to get them re-read.
Also: How will you cope with changes to other key/values in the plist, made by the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to toggle the state of **Text Substitutions** by swapping the **~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist** *file*, you would need to have a way to update the cached copy of it in memory. If you are an **Objective-C** programmer and have **Xcode** you could roll-your-own *app* to update the *file* and what's cached in memory. Sans that, here is a method using a *third-party command line utility*, [**`shortcuts`**](https://github.com/rodionovd/shortcuts/), and a *shell script* that works for me.

The **bash** *shell script* I've written uses the `shortcuts` *binary executable* to **backup**, **delete** and **restore** the **Text Substitutions**. The **backup** and **restore** are simple and straight forward compared to deleting the **Text Substitutions** as `shortcuts` can only delete one *shortcut* at a time. It's relatively quick. I have 200+ items in my **Replace** | **With** *list* and the *script* takes ~4 seconds to delete them, and a fraction of a second to restore them.

This was tested under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

**Note:** First make a manual backup of your **Text Substitutions** by going to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Text**, pressing **⌘A** to highlight all entries of **Replace** | **With** *list*, then *click-hold* with the *mouse*, then drag and drop to the **Desktop**, or any *folder* of a **Finder** *window*.

This will create a *file* named **Text Substitutions.plist** that can be dragged and dropped onto the **Replace** | **With** *list* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Text** to manually restore.

The *example* **shell script** *code* in conjunction with the `shortcuts` *command line utility* does it own backup and restores from its backup, but always make the manual backup described above just to have if ever needed.

---

Install [**`shortcuts`**](https://github.com/rodionovd/shortcuts/) by one of the methods mentioned in the link.

I downloaded the *source code*, reviewed and verified there was nothing ominous in the *code*, then built it using **Xcode**.

It's also available thru **Homebrew**, in **Terminal** `brew install rodionovd/taps/shortcuts`, or download as a [pre-built binary](https://github.com/rodionovd/shortcuts/releases).

---

**Note:** The following instructions and *example* **shell script** *code* are for use as an executable *shell script* in **Terminal**, and or can be used in a **Run Shell Script** *action* in an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* and assigned a *keyboard shortcut* in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

I'd suggest testing as an executable *shell script* first to ensure that it works for you, then use the *example* **shell script** *code* in an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*.

In **Terminal**, run the following *compound command*:

<sup>Assumes the `pwd` is your **HOME** *directory*.</sup>

```bash
f=trw; touch "$f"; open -e "$f"; chmod +x "$f"
```

<sup>**Note:** `trw` = **Toggle Replace With** (Had to name it something.)</sup>

In the opened **trw** *document* copy and paste the *example* **shell script** *code* into it, then save and close it.

Back in **Terminal**:

```
./trw
```

Will toggle the state of the **Text Substitutions**.

<sup>**Note:** After testing, move `trw` to a *directory* defined in the `PATH` to be available without typing: `./`</sup>

---

*Example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# set -e
# set -x 

shortcuts="/usr/local/bin/shortcuts"
automator=false # true or false


message() {
    [ "${1}" == "xmissing" ] && msg=" The 'shortcuts' executable is missing!"
    [ "${1}" == "already" ] && msg=" The text substitutions deletion is already in progress!"
    [ "${1}" == "backedup" ] && msg=" The text substitutions have been backed up."
    [ "${1}" == "nobackup" ] && msg=" No text substitutions to backup or restore!"
    [ "${1}" == "restored" ] && msg=" The text substitutions have been restored."
    [ "${1}" == "deleting" ] && msg=" The text substitutions deletion is in progress..."
    [ "${1}" == "finished" ] && msg=" The text substitutions deletion has completed."
    [ $automator == false ] && printf '%s\n' "${msg}"
    [ $automator == true ] && printf '%s\n' "$(date -j) ${msg}" >> message.txt
    [ $automator == true ] && [ -n "${2}" ] && \
    osascript -e "display notification \"${msg}\" with title \"Toggle Replace With\""
}

backupdir="$HOME/Library/Application Support/com.$USER.shortcuts"
[ ! -d "${backupdir}" ] && mkdir -p "${backupdir}"
cd "${backupdir}" || exit
backup="${backupdir}/Text_Substitutions.plist"
lockdir="/private/tmp/com.$USER.shortcuts"
[ ! -e "${lockdir}" ] && mkdir -p "${lockdir}"
cd "${lockdir}" || exit

if [ ! -x "${shortcuts}" ]; then
    message "xmissing"
    [ $automator == true ] && message "xmissing" "notification"
    exit    
fi

if [ -e ".lock" ]; then
    message "already"
    [ $automator == true ] && message "already" "notification"
    exit
fi

contents="$(defaults read -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems)"
empty='(
)'

if [ ! -e "${backup}" ] && [ "${contents}" != "${empty}" ]; then
    "${shortcuts}" read --as-plist | tee "${backup%.*}.$(date '+%s').plist" > "${backup}"
    message "backedup"
elif [ -e "${backup}" ] && [ "${contents}" != "${empty}" ]; then
    "${shortcuts}" read --as-plist | tee "${backup%.*}.$(date '+%s').plist" > "${backup}"
    message "backedup"
elif [ ! -e "${backup}" ] && [ "${contents}" == "${empty}" ]; then
    message "nobackup"
    [ $automator == true ] && message "nobackup" "notification"
    exit
fi

if [ "${contents}" == "${empty}" ]; then
    "${shortcuts}" import "${backup}"
    message "restored"
    [ $automator == true ] && message "restored" "notification"
else
    touch ".lock"
    message "deleting"
    [ $automator == true ] && message "deleting" "notification"
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        "${shortcuts}" delete "${line}"
    done <<< "$("$shortcuts" read | awk 'sub(/^"/, "", $2) sub(/"$/, "", $2) $1 ~ /^[0-9]+:/ { print $2 }')"
    sleep 1
    rm ".lock"
    message "finished"
    [ $automator == true ] && message "finished" "notification"
fi
```

---

**Notes:**

As coded, the *example* **shell script** *code* assume the `shortcuts` executable is located at `/usr/local/bin/shortcuts`, change as applicable. It is coded like this as `/usr/local/bin/` is not in the `PATH` passed to a **Run Shell Script** *action* in an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*.

The first time the *shell script* is run it creates a backup of the **Text Substitutions** to restore from, **so it is imperative that there actually be some *text substitutions* to backup**! A current backup is made each time prior to deleting them from the **~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist** *file* and is restored from the last backup.

The reason a *third-party application* is being used is in this use case it does something that the **macOS** default utilities cannot do, which is dynamically update the changes to the system. In other words, the `defaults` *command* as well as the `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` *command* in this use case does not update the system to the changes and has the same issue as swapping out the **~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist** *file*.

When using the *example* **shell script** *code* in a **Run Shell Script** *action* in an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, you need to set `automator=true` in the line after, e.g., `shortcuts="/usr/local/bin/shortcuts"`

Backups are saved to:

```
$HOME/Library/Application Support/com.$USER.shortcuts/Text_Substitutions.plist
```

The *example* **shell script** *code* when run as an executable *shell script* outputs messages to `stdout` and you see them as you go, however, when used in a **Run Shell Script** *action* in an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* messages are displayed in **Notification Center** and also log to:

```
/private/tmp/com.$USER.shortcuts/message.txt
```

I will try you add comments to the *code* and or add additional notes here in the next couple of days.

---

[image]

---

**Disclaimer Note:** The *example* **shell script** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.

Comment: This is exactly what I looked for. Many many thanks for such an exhaustive answer!
I would have started looking for `defaults`
  but, as you explained it would have been useless.
This works also for me with **German (Switzerland)** and **MacOS 10.15.7**.

Answer (score 1):

TextView windows that use macOS's Text Replacement usually provide a menu item to toggle Text Substitution off and on.

**Edit > Substitutions > Text Replacement**

[image]

You can set a keyboard shortcut for this menu item in **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts**.

[image]

(Here I've done it just for TextEdit, but you can do it for All Applications if you want.)

Toggling the key command gives me the following, when I type `omw`:

[image]

This achieves your goal of switching the replacement status without the complicated effort of maintaining and switching two complete preference files.